# Removing and adding an attribute to an html string in node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

So on my node.js backend I have an object with a `content` property which contains an HTML string. Now in there there is an img element where I would like to replace the attribute src, which is now a base64 string, to a path to my uploads folder. How can I change this src attribute?

**this is req.body.content. I would like to replace the base64 src of the img element to something I choose**

```
{ content: '<p><br></p><p><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOEAAADhCAMAAAAJbSJIAAAAmVBMV.. }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know for sure that there is just one image in your string, you can use a regular expression to replace:

```
let new_content = content.replace(/src="[^"]+"/, 'src="new contents of the attribute"');
```

This will replace **every src attribute** in your html, so make sure you don't have multiple.
If you have a more specific need, I normally use cheerio (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) to load in html and edit it like I would in jquery(-ish).

(The `[^"]+` in the regular expression stand for "Match multiple characters that are not `"`", which is normally how I select something inside a known boundary)

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at both options :)

Answer (score 2):

you can replace that string with a regular expression

```
let newPath = "some/where/local/img.png";
let replaced = req.body.content.replace(/src="(.+?)"/igm, "src='"+newPath+'")
```

if you don't know the html structure and e.g need to find all images, you should use something like `cheerio` or `jsdom` to parse the html string, make changes in the virtual dom.